# Title: Image not displaying in React component despite correct file path and syntax

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing an issue where an image is not displaying properly in my React component. I have verified that the file path is correct, the image file exists in the expected location, and I'm using the correct syntax to render the image. However, only the alt text or container elements are visible, and the image itself is not displayed.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

[image]

[image]

and the image is broken in UI

[image]

and the actual location of the image file is

[image]
Additional Details:

The image file is named "ef334f41-d35a-4058-87a0-d01cb565d41b.png".
The image file is located in the correct directory relative to my React project.
I have verified that the brand.file_name value is correctly set to the image file name.

I have already checked the following:

The image file extension is indeed ".png".
The image file size is within acceptable limits.
There are no errors or warnings in the network requests related to the image.

Despite these checks, the image is not displaying in the UI. Could there be any other factors causing this issue? Any suggestions or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you confirm where is the image? Is it on local or hosted somewhere?

Comment: If it is local, can you confirm if it is stored in public or src

Comment: Hi Tapan, It is in local in src . I have added the image which shows the path

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens due to the exact file location. So, you may try as:

```
<img src="exact file path" alt=""Product image />
```

and should check like this then you should try another way too it it didn't work